# Multiple custom graphics object inheriting from ChartContainer

Tags: matlab, oop, graph

I am trying to write a custom chart (or graphical object, rather), and I would like to plot several of them in a single figure. I am following this guide, but I keep getting:

```
Error using matlab.graphics.chartcontainer.ChartContainer
Adding TestChart to axes is not supported. Turn hold off.
```

In my custom class I am combining a line and a surface, but this a minimal class works as an example:

```
classdef TestChart < matlab.graphics.chartcontainer.ChartContainer
    properties (Access = private, Transient, NonCopyable)        
        % Chart axes.
        HandleLine(1,1) %  Handle of the line object
    end
    properties 
        Axes
        XData double {mustBeReal}
        YData double {mustBeReal}
        ZData double {mustBeReal}
    end 
    
    methods (Access = protected)
        function setup(this)
           this.Axes = getAxes(this);
           % Create line handle
           this.HandleLine = plot3(this.Axes, NaN, NaN, NaN, '-o');
        end
        
        function update(this)
            this.HandleLine.XData = this.XData;
            this.HandleLine.YData = this.YData;
            this.HandleLine.ZData = this.ZData;   
        end
    end
end
```

And then, if I try creating two of them:

```
a = TestChart('XData', [0 0], 'YData', [0 0], 'ZData', [1 2]);
b = TestChart('XData', [0 0], 'YData', [0 0], 'ZData', [5 8]);
```

I get the error saying "Adding TestChart to axes is not supported. Turn hold off.".
Is it possible to create custom graphics object that can be plotted several times in the same axex ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `ChartContainer` is new-ish, it's worth specifying your MATLAB version

Comment: Do you specifically want to be able to `hold` your chart objects, or would achieving multiple plots within a single chart object be a viable solution?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the nuance, but I want to plot multiple custom objects in the same axis, together with other standard plots (2D and 3D).

Comment: I mean a chart object can contain the ability to plot multiple things, like if xdata and ydata were matrices it could plot multiple lines. The `hold` would happen internally to the update fcn, and you'd only need one object so wouldn't violate this apparent limitation

Comment: Ah I understand; no that's a workaround that I alredy implemented in my class, but it's not the same. The method cannot be generalized, because if you want to combine this custom object with other standard plots, you have to embed everything in the same class, which is not very practical. I would really like to `hold`!

Comment: Why don't you just do what it says and type: `hold off` in the terminal?  See what it does then if you want to add that into your code...

Comment: @Matt If you `hold off` your first object will simply be deleted when you plot the second one. I need several custom objects and other standard plots in the same axis.